# How properly overload size() method/operator in Matlab

Tags: matlab, size, overloading, operator-keyword

I have some class with the property val

```
classdef SomeClass < handle

properties
   val;
end
methods
    function sz = size(this,varargin)
        sz = builtin('size',this.val,varargin{:});
    end;
end
end
```

supposedly it should be the proper way to overload this method to get the proper sizes of object of class SomeClass if it is defined as matrix, ie. val is a matrix. Assignment like

```
a = size(b) % b is SomeClass object
```

works, however

```
[a,b] = size(b)
```

does not. It causes an error "Too many output arguments.", while built in method size for doubles (which the val actually is) work with this syntax.

Can anyone give me a hint. What is an issue in this case ?

Comment: The method `size` only takes 2 arguments, `size(var, dim)`. Further, the method that you have defined allows only one output argument. Try to use `varagout` for variable output arguments.

Comment: @patrik I agree totally with `varargout`... however size can also take 1 argument: e.g. `size(var)` the `varargin` usage allow this to be called still

Comment: @RTL You are right of course. I just thought that the user expected to have more than 1 variable in `varargin` due to the `{:}`. Normally you can have something like `function varargout = size(this.val, dim), if nargin == 1, dim = 1; ...` or else an error check: `if numel(varargin)>1, error('errMsg')`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in comments by patrik use `varargout`...
With the addition of `nargout` the size method can be implemented as follows:

```
function varargout = size(this,varargin)
    [varargout{1:nargout}] = builtin('size',this.val,varargin{:});
end
```

---

As a side note due to the possible corner case of `val` having a class using an overloaded size method the use of builtin could be replaced with a direct call to `size`.

This however comes with more risk of breaking, for example:

```
Obj = SomeClass();
Obj.val = Obj;
size(Obj);
```

would hit an infinite loop...

Comment: Thanks, I tried to use varargout, however in a different way, without [] and {}, thus apparently doing it wrong .